# SystemVerilog disable cover property after hit

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have a few cover property's that I expect to fire pretty frequently, and I'm seeing they are starting to impact my simulation performance because they are firing so frequently. I don't want to remove them because I want to make sure I am still hitting these properties, but I don't care how many times I hit them. Is there a way to disable the cover property after it's hit once so it won't hinder simulation performance?

```
B2BReq : cover property ( 
  @(posedge CLK iff !RESET)
  Intf.ReqValid ##1 Intf.ReqValid
);
```

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
bit cov_disable;
B2BReq : cover property ( 
  @(posedge CLK iff !RESET) disable iff(cov_disable)
  Intf.ReqValid ##1 Intf.ReqValid |=> cov_disable = 1
);
```

But this is incorrect syntax. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tools automatically disable a cover directive when it hits a certain limit. I know that in Questa, the default is disabling after 1 hit.

Also, you may get better performance modeling what you want with a simple implication

```
B2BReq : cover property ( 
  @(posedge CLK iff !RESET)
  Intf.ReqValid |-> ##1 Intf.ReqValid;
);
```

BTW, the syntax you were looking for was

```
bit cov_disable;
B2BReq : cover property ( 
  @(posedge CLK iff !RESET) disable iff(cov_disable)
  Intf.ReqValid ##1 Intf.ReqValid |=> (1,cov_disable = 1);
);
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error when I try to assign a global variable from within the cover property "Only local variables can be assigned in match item list". Is it possible to set some global flag like this from inside a cover property?

Comment: How do you know this is the cause of your performance problems?did you try my first suggestion?

Comment: I'm using Questa coverage viewer to see the "Peak Memory Time" of cover directives, and this is at the top of the list. I tried your suggested change and I don't see any difference in the peak memory time.

Comment: I think that's my problem. The "Peak memory time" is jus the simulation time at which the peak memory was achieved, not how much time was spent allocating/deallocating memory for this cover.